# How to convert PDF version to 1.7 ExtensionLevel 8 using Ghostscript

Tags: ghostscript

I am able to convert the PDF version from 1.5 to 1.7 with the below Ghostscript code but how to convert "PDF version 1.7 ExtensionLevel 8"?

```
gs -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dFastWebView=true -dCompatibilityLevel=1.7 -sOutputFile=output.pdf input.pdf
```

Answer (score 0):

What exactly are you expecting to happen here ?

Your command line doesn't actually do anything except write a different version number into the PDF header. The same would be true of writing an extension version, all it does is change the 'version', it doesn't affect the content of the PDF file.

Ghostscript's pdfwrite device doesn't even use the features of PDF 1.5 (with a couple of minor exceptions), so what do you expect to gain even by producing a PDF 1.7 file ?

Lying about the minimum required version (which is what you are doing when you change the version like this) simply means that older PDF consumers might fail to open the file (or give a warning) because they believe it will use features which they don't support. Since the PDF file doesn't use those features, you are actually making the file **less** portable by doing this.

FWIW Ghostscript's pdfwrite device can now produce PDF 2.0 files.

If you absolutely are insistent about doing this you can 'probably' add an Extensions dictionary to the document Catalog using pdfmarks, but I'm not 100% confident.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.<br/>

The ghostscript code showed above is an example only. If any PDF document is less than 1.5 version then the same document has to be converted to "1.7 ExtensionLevel 8", this is my requirement.<br/>

I have done the same (i.e PDF version 1.7 with ExtensionLevel 8) with Adobe Acrobat 10 Professional, but I need to do the same thing using Ghostscript (without Acrobat software).<br/>

Kindly advise.

Comment: But you haven't said **why** you have to convert it to a higher version, or what you expect to gain, and I have explained why its not really a good idea. All the advice I have to offer is in my reply.

Comment: Actually, "PDF version 1.7 with ExtensionLevel 8" is one of our clients requirements and we cannot ask them, what is the purpose of pdf version 1.7. Here my aim to convert this same format without Adobe Acrobat professional software dependency. Is it possible to create this format with Ghostscript or any other tools?

Comment: I think you should go back to your clients and ask, its not an unreasonable question. I should also point out that Ghostscript is licenced under the AGPL, if you are considering shipping it to your client then you would potentially be in violation of the licence. Other than that, well you already said you can do it with Acrobat. You **might** be able to do it with Ghostscript, I haven't tried to create the relevant pdfmarks.